# Run headless server without GPU on Ryzen 5 3600

Tags: boot, graphics-card, bios, motherboard, computer-building

I just looked up hardware components for a server I want to build. However I am not sure if I am able to boot my build with an headless operating system like Debian. Do I need a dedicated GPU for my build? Do I need to configure specific options in the BIOS?

Components:

- AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6x 3.60GHz So.AM4 BOX
- Gigabyte Aorus Pro WIFI (rev. 1.0) AMD B450 So.AM4 Dual Channel DDR4 Mini-ITX Retail
- 400 Watt be quiet! Pure Power 11 CM Modular 80+ Gold
- 1000GB Samsung 970 Evo M.2 2280 PCIe 3.0 x4 NVMe 1.3 3D-NAND TLC (MZ-V7E1T0BW)
- 32GB G.Skill Aegis DDR4-3200 DIMM CL16 Dual Kit

https://www.mindfactory.de/shopping_cart.php/basket_action/load_basket_extern/id/f07aeb22147ba344f279f8bc715fba123bf0320674418075ed8

Comment: How would you even access the firmware setup without a graphics card? ;-)

Comment: @DanielB The motherboard has built-in DisplayPort & HDMI Ports

Comment: Sure it has. They depend on the CPU having an integrated GPU. A Ryzen 5 3600 does not have that.

Comment: Ah, you got me there :D Although the XT edition does so maybe a simple upgrade...